# How to do the minus operation given 2 columns using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

allpairs

```
user1 user2
1     1
2     1
3     1
1     2
2     2
3     2
1     3
2     3
3     3
```

likesPairs

```
user1 user2
1     2
2     1
3     1
```

I want to do allPairs - likedPairs to get the relation

notliked

```
user1 user2
1     1
2     2
3     2
1     3
2     3
3     3
```

I tried something like this but it just errors

```
select user1, user2 
from allpairs NOT IN likespairs
```

Comment: is 2,1 on likespairs = 1,2 in allpairs?

Comment: I don't understand the question, you can do something like this in mysql
`FROM allpairs a JOIN likespairs WHERE (a.user1, a.user2) != (b.user1, b.user2)` or something along those lines

Comment: like the set difference (1,2,3,4) - (2,3) = (1, 4).

Comment: This is an exclusion join, which can be written using a LEFT JOIN in conjunction with an IS NULL filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like `not exists`:

```
select ap.*
from allpairs ap
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from likespairs lp 
    where lp.user1 = ap.user1 and lp.user2 = ap.user2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the `LEFT JOIN` can be used with check for `NULL` values:

```
select allpairs.*
from allpairs
left join likespairs 
    on (allpairs.user1 = likespairs.user1 and allpairs.user2 = likespairs.user2)
where likespairs.user1 is null;
```

[Here you can try the SQL code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=308681771ae27ba74b09e64914ec94c5&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

If pair's order not a matter you can add next into `LEFT JOIN` condition:

```
select allpairs.*
from allpairs
left join likespairs on (
    (allpairs.user1 = likespairs.user1 and allpairs.user2 = likespairs.user2) or
    (allpairs.user2 = likespairs.user1 and allpairs.user1 = likespairs.user2)
)
where likespairs.user1 is null;
```

[Try SQL here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=24db54eee507d3e3f6c497477f7be005&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)